# Set a minimal default weight for products in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product

I'm trying to add a default product shipping weight to WooCommerce in my functions.php file but is not working, I'm not sure if I'm using the right snippets or missing parts of the snippet.

Here's that I'm using,

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_weight', 'woocommerce_product_get_weight_filter');

function woocommerce_product_get_weight_filter($weight) {
  $default_weight = 0.1; 
  if ((!is_numeric($weight)) || ($weight <= 0.001)) {
    return $default_weight;
  }
  return $weight;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with `empty()` and the hook for product variations :

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_weight', 'woocommerce_product_get_weight_filter', 10, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_weight', 'woocommerce_product_get_weight_filter', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_product_get_weight_filter( $weight, $product ) {
    if ( empty($weight) || $weight <= 0.001 ) {
        return 0.1;
    }
    return $weight;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> This will not work in admin product edit pages in the weight setting field. The only available hooks **are working for "view" context** and **not in "edit" context** *(as in backend)*…

Comment: Okay, is the weight suppose to show in the edit product page in the shipping tab?

Comment: @cubaton3 No the default weight is not shown in backend product edit pages as those composite hooks only work for "view" context and not "edit" context (backend product edit pages use "edit" context on all `WC_Product` methods)